# Output python into python-readable format

Tags: python, arrays, file

We're using a python based application which reads a configuration file containing a couple of arrays:

Example layout of config file:

```
array1 = [
'bob',
'sue',
'jayne'
]
```

Currently changes to the configuration are done by hand, but I've written a little interface to streamline the process (mainly to avoid errors).

It currently reads in the existing configuration, using a simple "import". However what I'm not sure how to do, is get my script to write it's output in valid python, so that the main application can read it again.

How can I can dump the array back into the file, but in valid python?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally using repr() will create a string that can be re-avaluated. But pprint does a little nicer output.

```
from pprint import pprint

outf.write("array1 = "); pprint(array1, outf)
```

Comment: I'll just append the following: To read the string back in as valid python, use eval().

Comment: For safety, avoid `eval()` and use [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html?highlight=literal_eval#ast.literal_eval) for Python 2.6+, or a [2.4/2.5-compatible backport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642987/converting-tuple-to-dictionary/5643315#5643315).

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) or [YAML](http://pyyaml.org/) (Less verbose than JSON) for configuration files. That way, the configuration file becomes more readable for the less pythonate ;) It's also easier to throw adequate errors, e.g. if the configuration is incomplete.

To save python objects you can always use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html).

Answer (score 1):

`repr(array1)` (and write that into the file) would be a very simple solution, but it should work here.